# Using GNU screen to create a split screen environment from command line

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, gnu-screen

Could someone please point me towards the syntax for using GNU screen from the command line. On a previous cluster, I managed to create a bash script that would create X number of tiled shells, each ssh-ing into a remote node and running htop. This way I could monitor an entire cluster from one shell. I have lost access to that cluster (and the work on it), but I need to do the same thing again.

I do remember seeing an answered question on StackExchange, SuperUser, or LinuxQuestions which is what I based my previous script on, but I cannot for the life of me find it again, so I am having to ask again.

Thankyou,

Stuart

** Please do not suggest using a screenrc file. That is not the ideal way of achieving what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Try [cluster ssh](http://sourceforge.net/projects/clusterssh/). You can find many tutorial on line [e.g this article](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/413853:managing-multiple-linux-servers-with-clusterssh) with a simple command line.

```
 cssh -l <username> <machinename1> <machinename2> <machinename3>.
```

Mybe you can find interesting to give a look to this [article](http://archive09.linux.com/feature/151340)

Extended synopsis

```
cssh <-s server[[:'cmds'][,server[:'cmd;cmd2'],server]]... | 
-c config file> [-h] [-d <1-3>] [-n] [-p ] [-a]
             [-l ] [-q] [-b] [-x] [-y] [-e] [-C] [-P] [-S] [-e]
```

as command you can use `htop` or whatever else. You can give a look to the [cssh man page](http://cssh.sourceforge.net/docs/cssh_man.html).

Comment: Thanks for your input Hastur. However I should have been more specific, as I am SSH-ing into the head-node, I do not think I can use ClusterSSH as (from what I can tell) it only runs in X.

Comment: It seems that _"It requires the Perl libraries Tk (perl-tk on Debian or Ubuntu) and X11::Protocol (libx11-protocol-perl on Debian or Ubuntu), in addition to xterm and OpenSSH." [see here](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/413853:managing-multiple-linux-servers-with-clusterssh). From [the man page instead](http://cssh.sourceforge.net/docs/cssh_man.html) they report need of Perl 5.8.x.( _Cssh requires Net::SSH::Perl to be installed properly in order to work._). If X is installed on the head-node you can always connect with `ssh -X head-node`. [Ps>You're welcome]

Comment: Thanks Hastur. I'm going to steer away from that at the moment. I have the cluster configured with a very stripped down OS at the moment, and would prefer not to bulk it up by running X.